# SPLIT_BUNDLE 6: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section:

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I have a basic json application that I developed with Flutter. This app contains ads and in-app purchases. Google has sent warnings of data breach several times.

the issues:

**SPLIT_BUNDLE 6: Policy Declaration -** Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - **Email Address**
**SPLIT_BUNDLE 6: Policy Declaration** - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - **Phone number**

There is no form available in the application. I would be very grateful if you could help me how to fill out the data security form.

[image]

Comment: You should add a screenshot with English information.